# Generating a TDS content item package that has certain items in only one language

Tags: tds

A client has an unusual process where a small subset of their content items are stored in their code repository in a TDS project.

The project is multilingual. Currently, changes to several of these content item are approved only in one language. So during the next couple of weeks, for all deployments, the client wants these items to be updated only in a single language, with all other language version remaining as they are.

Is there a way to set up several specific items in TDS so that when a package is created, only one particular language version of these items will be included in the package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TDS, the current way to only push part of an item, but not the whole thing is to use Field Level Deployments.

For each item, right click on it and select 'Field Level Deployment'.
Now select each of the fields, for each language that you wish to push.

[image]

(Note: Ensure that the item is also marked as 'DeployOnce', not 'AlwaysUpdate' so that the full item is not pushed on deployment).

I understand this could take a lot of time if you have a lot of items.... however this sounds more like deploying content items with TDS, instead of developer items, which isn't ideal anyway.